# Wordpress image size crop but always proportional

Tags: wordpress, image, crop

I am have set an `add_image_size` function that is often larger in only one dimension than the uploaded image.  This results in an image that has one dimension cropped and one dimension that remains un-cropped resulting in an image that loses it's proportions.  As a result I have a set of images that are not equally proportioned.

The desired outcome is that if the image is cropped in one dimension then it is proportionally cropped in the other dimension, meaning that I can upscale it if required with CSS.

For example, my image size is 1200 x 900.  If I upload an image that is 1100 x 1467.  The output is an image that is 1100 x 900.  However, what I require is an image that is 1100 x 825 (the same proportion as the 1200 x 900 image size I set, but smaller as the image wasn't large enough to fulfill this size).

Here is the function with the arguments:

`add_image_size( 'landscape-huge', 1200, 600, true);`

I can't seem to find a way of doing this though - is this possible?

Comment: can you please explain it in detail so that we it would easy to get your problem..!!

Comment: Do you set the `$crop`-parameter for [`add_image_size()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)?

Comment: @Max yes, it is cropping just not proportionately, only cropping the part of the image that outlies the crop boundaries.

Comment: Do you mind adding the code you're currently using to your question? If you set the `$crop` parameter to `false` in the `add_image_size()` it should maintain the aspect ratio aka do a 'soft-crop'.

Comment: @Max - I've set it to true as I don't want to keep the aspect ratio of the image the same.  I want them to all be 1200:900 (4:3).  I've added the exact line where I specify the size to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Because it's wordpress default feature but u can change, go to wp-include folder then media.php and find these lines

```
$s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );

$s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );
```

and change to

```
 $s_x = 0;

 $s_y = 0;
```

it will work for you.

Comment: You should never edit core files as they will get overwritten when you update WordPress. This is what filters and actions are for.